# uniform convergence $\sum_{n\ge 0} \ln(1+e^{-nx})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

how prove uniform convergence : $$x\in (0,+\infty) \\ \sum_{n\ge 0} \ln(1+e^{-nx})$$

we have : $$\ln(1+e^{-nx}) \le 
e^{-nx}$$

and series :$\sum_{n\ge 0} e^{-nx} $ converge (série géométrique)
so:series $\sum_{n\ge 0} \ln(1+e^{-nx})$ Uniform convergence

that is Corect or Not ?

if not correct . How prove Uniforme convergence .

Comment: *Hint:* Set $x=1/n$ ...

Comment: Good Idea , thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your argument is not correct. You are right that
$$
 0 \le \ln(1+e^{-nx}) \le  e^{-nx}
$$
for all $x$ and $n$, and that $\sum_n e^{-nx}$ converges for all $x$, but that does not prove the uniform convergence. You probably want to apply the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test), but for that you need a sequence $M_n$ with
$$
 0 \le \ln(1+e^{-nx}) \le M_n
$$
and $\sum_n M_n < \infty$. The important point is that the bound $M_n$ does not depend on $x$.

Actually the series is *not* uniformly convergent. With $f_n(x) = \ln(1+e^{-nx})$ we have
$$
 f_n(1/n) = \ln(1+1/e) > 0
$$
so that $(f_n)$ does not uniformly converge to zero. Consequently, $\sum_n f_n(x)$ is not uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 1):

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\displaystyle R_n : x \longmapsto  \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} \ln(1+e^{-kx})$.

To see whether the series is uniformly convergent, we have to see if the *sequence* $(R_n)_{n \geq 0}$ converges uniformly to the null function.

But for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, one has
\begin{align*} ||R_n||_\infty \geq R_n\left( \dfrac{1}{n+1}\right) &= \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} \ln(1+e^{-k/(n+1)}) \\ &= \ln(1+e^{-1})+\sum_{k=n+2}^{+\infty} \ln(1+e^{-k/(n+1)}) \\
&\geq \ln(1+e^{-1})
\end{align*}

Hence $||R_n||_\infty$ does not tend to $0$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$, and the series is not uniformly convergent over $(0,+\infty)$.